# Help with some capacitators

Tags: capacitor, dc-motor

So i have some 10ųf capacitator s that  i think can withstands the maximum voltage and current input of 11.1V and 3amps but they are extremly small and the legs are really thin ,just kinda need the security to know that i can use them

im using it for a 3 phase motor

Comment: How can we know that without a data sheet for the caps and your motor?

Comment: What are the capacitors rated for?

Comment: https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F123134531038

Comment: "im using it for a 3 phase motor" - how much voltage does this motor need? Is it a motor for a small drone or something? Or is it a motor connected to the mains? If it's the latter, please wear safety goggles... (i.e. magic smoke about to happen). No seriously, if your supply is any higher than 10V, don't even try!

Comment: Capacitor not   capacitator 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off the part about the thin legs, I doubt the capacitor can withstand a high amount of current. Assuming that the legs are made of copper (which is highly likely) you can base off how much current it can take (more like the max. current the legs will take before they melt) on this chart [here](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm).

It says that at a diameter of 1 mm, copper can take around 2.3 amps, and it goes down from there (in a non-linear fashion!).